# Commit specific save operation in django atomic transaction

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a view that is decorated with an atomic transaction. However, I'd always like to save a specific operation in this view. The operation is to call to a third party API and sometimes I need to refresh the token before the app can make the request. However, if there is a failure after this refresh then the new token does not get saved and is instead rolledback. How can I always make the save operation commit to the database? I've looked into using a [savepoint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/transactions/) but I'm not sure I'm on the right track.

`views.py`

```
@transaction.atomic
def my_view(request)
    from another_file import fx
    a = Mymodel.objects.first()
    fx(a)

    return a
```

`another_file.py`

```
   def fx(obj) 
       from django.db import transaction

       sid = transaction.savepoint()

       obj.token = 'jfkds'
       obj.save()
       transaction.savepoint_commit(sid)

       raise Exception
```

Answer (score 1):

Having had a similar problem where a user token is needed by 'process B' verifying authentication passed from 'process A' before the transaction in process A has committed:

To solve it I needed the 'Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)' call to commit in its own transaction whether or not there is already some surrounding transaction in progress. I think you are looking at the same issue with your question.

I used a separate database connection for the token handling. Thus in settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'mydbuser',
        'PASSWORD': DBPASSWORD}}
DATABASES['security'] = DATABASES['default']  # allow independent security transactions/connections
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['security.db_router.SecurityRouter']
```

The router ensures that the Token model is handled in the 'security' database. You can put the router where you like and link it using the router setting as above.:

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token


class SecurityRouter(object):

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return self.mine(model, **hints)

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return self.mine(model, **hints)

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        return True

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model=None, **hints):
        return True

    @staticmethod
    def mine(model, **hints):
        if model == Token:
            return 'security'
```

All use of the Token objects now takes place in the 'security' database. Thus user tokens are created in a transaction that is independent of your 'default' database transactions and which is immediate, like all django connections (unless you specify otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, and slightly easier, you can save and update the token first and then use a with block to make the rest of the view operations atomic:

```
# @transaction.atomic
def my_view(request)
    from another_file import fx
    with transaction.atomic():
        # this has to be atomic to avoid write-after-read conflicts
        a = Mymodel.objects.first()
        fx(a)
    with transaction.atomic():
        # do the rest of your view operations here including another get to Mymodel.objects.first()
        a = Mymodel.objects.first()
        # rest of view stuff goes here

    return a
```